# Syncing file between Android devices

Tags: android, synchronization, cloud, drive

I need to sync a file between multiple Android devices. The requirement is that each user will have it's own file (think of the file as the user own database of sorts). I ended up taking a look at Google's 'Backing up App Data to the Cloud' documentation for Android 5.1 and lower, however it's mentioned that the FileBackupHelper class is used. The class reference states that "This should be used only with small configuration files, not large binary files." Now, the file in question could be several megabytes in size which I guess would make it 'large'?

I researched some more for other alternatives and discovered that Google have a Drive API. I'm thinking of saving the file from the user device to Google Drive and sync whenever the file on the user device is updated. The only problem I see with this approach is that I'll have to develop my own conflict resolution in case the same file is updated on multiple devices which quite frankly I'd love to avoid. But if it cannot be avoided can someone point me out to a tutorial?

Is using the Drive API an acceptable approach and if not, what would be a better solution? I'm in no way a backend guy so ideally would like to look at other alternatives that do not require having my own server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best option I know is still Google Drive. But keep in mind that Google Drive doesn't sync files with the device unless the user or your app requests it. So yes, I believe you will have to do all the conflict resolution, plus pushing the syncs from and to the user's drive.